# CentOS 5.5 SSH with Key for non ROOT user

Tags: ssh, centos, key-authentication

I tried pretty much everything I could to make this work. I spent literally 6 hours on research and nothing helps to remove "Server refused our key" error.
My username I tried to make is "Testuser" but I logged in SSH as root, should I also `chown Testuser:Testuser authorized_keys`?

I originally tried this and everything alike: http://www.howtoforge.com/ssh_key_based_logins_putty_p3
Then I followed this and still does not work : http://www.walkernews.net/2009/03/22/how-to-fix-server-refused-our-key-error-that-caused-by-putty-generated-rsa-public-key/

Comment: So what precisely did you try? Copy paste any command that you typed and any file that you edited. My answer explains the most common difficulty; if it doesn't help, then **tell us what you tried**, don't just tell us that you tried something.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to log in as `Testuser`, then yes, you need to make sure that `~Testuser`, `~Testuser/.ssh` and `~Testuser/.ssh/authorized_keys` belong to the user `Testuser`, and that **all three** are **not writable by any other user**, i.e.

```
chown Testuser ~Testuser ~Testuser/.ssh ~Testuser/.ssh/authorized_keys
chmod go-w ~Testuser ~Testuser/.ssh ~Testuser/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Note that the prefered way to upload a new key to an account is to use `ssh-copy-id`. It would arrange for permissions to be correct.

You can also have `~Testuser/.ssh` and `~Testuser.ssh/authorized_keys` owned by root, but that's only for unusual setups where you don't want the user to be able to change the list of authorized keys. The file must be readable by `Testuser` in any case.